# IOException while changing from File to BufferedImage

Tags: java, ioexception, bufferedimage

Error: Unhandled exception type IOException.

```
File imgLoc = new File("player.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgLoc);
```

How do I get a bufferedImage from a file location?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct?  Try calling exists() on imgLoc to verify its existence before doing the ImageIO.read()

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace ? And is the file really a valid PNG ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of your problem is best determined by examining a stacktrace for the exception.

As a temporary measure, replace those two lines with the following:

```
File imgLoc = new File("player.png");
BufferedImage img;
try {
   img = ImageIO.read(imgLoc);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
   ex.printStackTrace();
   throw ex;
}
```

to send some diagnostics to standard error.  Run the modified app and post the resulting output.

Possible causes include:

- The file name is wrong,
- The file is not in the app's current directory,
- The file is not readable by the app due to operating system access controls,
- The file is readable but there is something wrong with its format,
- etcetera.

Answer (score 2):

Does the file exist ? Are you by chance reading from an unexpected directory ?

Try [File.exists()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) and/or [File.canRead()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29)